# Invalid syntax of Else: 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, continue

I'm a newbie  in python scripting and would like to know how to fix the code below. I would like to know how to solve the Invalid Syntax of Else statement, thank you!

```
import os
import zipfile

f = open("filelist.txt","w+")
path=("pathtofile")
directory=os.fsencode(path)
filenames = []
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".zip"):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r') as zipObj:
            contents = zipObj.namelist()

    listfile = (str(contents))
    remchar = "'[]"
    for char in remchar:
            a = listfile.replace(char,"")
    f.write (a)
    continue
    else:
        pass

    f.close()
```

Comment: Is this the actual indentation of your code?

Comment: Should y our code like `listfile` and `remchar` and your for loop be indented inside y our if statement? if not then you need to move your else above them so that after your if the next line of code at the same indentation is your else

Comment: The `if` statement ended when you didn't indent `listfile = ...`. What is `else` supposed to be part of?

Comment: If you are new you may want to start with the official Python Tutorial. The solution for your `else:` mistake is on https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements – and next time, please post the full traceback. For one, it tells us *exactly* at what line the error occurred. (It may tell us much more so don't omit anything of which you don't understand the need thereof.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that indentation in python is significant. Your `else:` statement has no matching `if` statement on the same level. Make sure to indent properly to achieve what you're looking for:

```
if filename.endswith(".zip"):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r') as zipObj:
        contents = zipObj.namelist()

        listfile = (str(contents))
        remchar = "'[]"
        for char in remchar:
            a = listfile.replace(char,"")
            f.write (a)
        continue
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The `else` statement is outside the end of the `if` one. You have to include an `else` right after you ended the other one. It's like this:

```
if filename.endswith(".zip"):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r') as zipObj:
        contents = zipObj.namelist()
else:
    pass
```

If you're just going to write `pass`, then you can directly ommit the `else`.